# How to merge two dictionaries and replace values based on key?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, replace

```
dict1 = [{"names": 'john, will', "age": 2, "score": 4.1}{"names": 'tom, sam', "age": 3, "score": 6}]
dict2 = {'john': '001','will': '002', 'tom': '003', 'sam': '004}
```

dict1 is a nested dictionary *in* a list and dict2 is a dictionary. I am trying to iterate over dict1 and replace the "names" values with values in dict2, based on matching keys.

The desired output would be:

```
dict3 = [{"names": '001, 002', "age": 2, "score": 4.1}{"names": '003, 004', "age": 3, "score": 6}]
```

Iterating through dict1 is what's stumping me. Also the fact that the strings/values in "names" are not separated. I attempted a dictionary comprehension with no luck.

```
{k: dict2.get(v, v) for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

I'm very much a beginner - I appreciate any help or guidance!

Comment: `A` is not a valid variable.

Comment: How is this related to `pandas`?

Comment: Looking for either a standard python solution or pandas solution.

Comment: `dict1` is not a valid literal, e.g. `x = ({"y": "AAA"}{"y": "BBB"})`. Do you want a list of dicts like `x = [{"y": "AAA"}, {"y": "BBB"}]`?

Comment: Oops! Updated it. Yes, looking for the output to be a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go over the list called `dict1` (yes, it's a list called `dict1`, confusing...) and for every element `x` go over its keys and values and if the key equals `names` then go over and replace the strings according to `dict2`, just remember to assign the resulting string back to the original `dict` since replace isn't performed in-place.

```
for x in dict1:
    for k, v in x.iteritems():
        if k == 'names':
            for kk, vv in dict2.iteritems():
                v = v.replace(kk, vv)
        x[k] = v


print(dict1)
> [{'age': 2, 'score': 4.1, 'names': '001, 002'}, {'age': 3, 'score': 6, 'names': '003, 004'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. First make sure your first dictionary is a valid list:

```py
A = [
    {"names": 'john, will', "age": 2, "score": 4.1},
    {"names": 'tom, sam', "age": 3, "score": 6}
]
B = {'john': '001', 'will': '002', 'tom': '003', 'sam': '004'}
```

Then you can apply this custom function which loops through your second dictionary and tries to replace every key it can find with its value:

```py
def replace_name(names):
    for k, v in B.items():
        names = names.replace(k, v)
    return names

df['names'].apply(replace_name)
```